# Handling Related Data when using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two Classes: LicenseType and EntityType.

```
[Table("LicenseType")]
public class LicenseType : ComplianceBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<Certification> _certifications = new List<Certification>();
    private List<EntityType> _entityTypes = new List<EntityType>();

    public List<EntityType> EntityTypes
    {
        get { return _entityTypes; }
        set { _entityTypes = value; }
    }

    public List<Certification> Certifications
    {
        get { return _certifications; }
        set { _certifications = value; }
    }
}
```

and

```
[Table("EntityType")]
public class EntityType : ComplianceBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<LicenseType> _licenseTypes = new List<LicenseType>();

    public List<LicenseType> LicenseTypes
    {
        get { return _licenseTypes; }
        set
        {
            _licenseTypes = value;
            //  OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The both derive from ComplianceBase,

```
public class ComplianceBase
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;


    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _id) return;
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

What I want is to be able to do is associate an EntityType with one or more LicenseTypes, so for instance, an EntityType "Primary Lender" could be associated with say two LicenseTypes, "Lender License" and "Mortgage License". In this situation, I want one record in the EntityType table, "Primary Lender" and two records in my LicenseType table: "Lender License" and "Mortgage License".

The code for adding related LicenseTypes to my EntityType is done by calling:

```
_currentEntity.LicenseTypes.Add(licenseType);
```

and then calling `_context.SaveChanges()`;

There is an additional table, "EntityTypeLicenseTypes" that serves as the lookup table to relate these two tables. There are two records to join the EntityType with the two related LicenseTypes.

And this works. However, my code also adds (it duplicates) the LicenseType record and adds it in the LicenseType table for those records that are being associated.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid the duplication you must *attach* the `licenseType` to the context:

```
_context.LicenseTypes.Attach(licenseType);
_currentEntity.LicenseTypes.Add(licenseType);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get an error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Ok - I got your solution to work - the problem was I was using two different instances of the DbContext - as soon as I "Shared" them, the system worked. Thanks!